# springboot-aop can't get Class Object of joinPoint arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I'am try to get some methods arguments by spring AOP,then try to use `getClass()` to get arguments's Class Object,but i can't get the Class Object such as `java.sql.Time` ,it will throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`. there is the code fragment:

`com.example.vzard.web.TUserController.java`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@TimeStamp(type = TUser.class)
 public boolean addUser(TUser user, Object o, Time time){
        return itUserService.insertAllColumn(user);
    }
```

`com.example.vzard.annotation.TimeStamp.java`

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TimeStamp {
    Class type() default Object.class;

    TimeStampRank rank() default TimeStampRank.FULL;
}
```

`com.example.vzard.aspect.TimeStampAspect.java`

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.vzard.annotation.TimeStamp)")
public void pointCut(){

}

@Before("pointCut() && @annotation(timeStamp)")
public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint,TimeStamp timeStamp){
    Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Class type = timeStamp.type();

    Object[] argList = joinPoint.getArgs();
    System.out.println(argList.length);
    for (Object arg : argList) {
        //there will throw Exception
        log.info(arg.getClass().toString());

    }

}
```

i find it maybe in connection with whether the argument class have empty constructor,when i replace `java.sql.Time` in some Class with empty constructor
it will be OK,but i am not sure whether it is real reason.